# Who reads the value of ENV['SSL_CERT_FILE']?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, sinatra

I used to receive the following error:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
from C:/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678:in `connect'
```

after reading through [this](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyinstaller/browse_thread/thread/d9c9878eb7e67b1e?pli=1), I discovered that the fix is to download the cacert.pem file from [here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html). The post recommends doing something like this:

```
ENV['SSL_CERT_FILE'] = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),"cacert.pem")
```

And, indeed, this solves the problem. However, who reads the value of `SSL_CERT_FILE`? Altering the environment doesn't seem like "the Ruby way" of doing it. I'm looking for a solution that could work with both Rails and Sinatra.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The openssl library uses the SSL_CERT_FILE environment variable.