# OpenSSL + Self Signed Cert = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache, ssl, openssl, open-uri

I've been trying to use an SSL (SAN) certificate for our internal Rails app.

I have created the certificate files using OpenSSL and have them working nicely with Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName server-name
  RailsEnv uat

  DocumentRoot /var/www/server-name/current/public
  <Directory /var/www/server-name/current/public>
    AllowOverride All
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/hostname.cer
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/hostname.key
</VirtualHost>
```

This works fine.

My issue is when using `open-uri` to communicate with some of the Rails controllers, i get the error message:

```
require "net/https"

uri = URI.parse("https://server-name.domain.com/controller.json?date=2013-09-03") 
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.start {
  http.request_get(uri.path) {|res|
    print res.body
  }
}

OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

I have seen many StackOverflow articles which suggest simply turning off SSL verification, using:

```
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

But I do not consider this a satisfactory approach. I have also seen articles which suggest i need to point `open-uri` to `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` which is clearly for public certificates. So for my self signed certificate, i tried the following:

```
uri = URI.parse("https://server-name.domain.com/controller.json?date=2013-09-03") 
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
if uri.scheme == "https"  # enable SSL/TLS
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
  http.ca_file = "/etc/apache2/ssl/host-name.cer"
end
http.start {
  http.request_get(uri.path) {|res|
    print res.body
  }
}
```

Which worked.

My question is, how do i tell OpenSSL / OpenURI to always look in the `/etc/apache2/ssl/` directory in addition to its current search path? I don't want to specify the path (which will change as the host name changes depending where we are working from) in each request i make.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extracted from [here](https://mislav.net/2013/07/ruby-openssl/):

> If there’s already a CA bundle on disk that you want to use, point `SSL_CERT_FILE` or `SSL_CERT_DIR` environment variables to it, or set the `ca_file=` or `ca_path=` properties in Net::HTTP.

So all you have to do is this

```
ENV['SSL_CERT_FILE'] = "your certificate path"
```

and all should work.

You might find this resource useful:

- [Who reads the value of ENV['SSL_CERT_FILE']?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564940/who-reads-the-value-of-envssl-cert-file)